# C# How to Pass String Null to stored procedures

Tags: c#

I want to send String Null to SqlServer from C#

```
Pat.Add_Dis(Convert.ToInt32(TXT_Dis_ID.Text), Convert.ToInt32(TXT_ID.Text), TXT_Dis_A.Text, DBNull.Value.ToString(), A ,TXT_NULL.Text);
```

i try many way but every time send empty field or 'NULL' like this

i try to send  Null like this but String value

Comment: Why you want to pass the string "NULL" to the SP? You know that this string is not the same as the value `NULL`?

Comment: We don't now what is happening inside `Pat.Add_Dis` so can't really help. But i'm sure `DBNull.Value.ToString()` is wrong. Try using null as parameter for that method and inside `Pat.Add_Dis` you may need to translate that to DBNull.Value (without the ToString()).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing what ADO.NET tooling you're using here, it is hard to say specifically, but *in general*, a database null should be represented with `DBNull.Value`; this can be done tersely when packing parameters as:

```cs
someParam.Value = ((object)value) ?? DBNull.Value;
```

If you pass `null` as the value, that is interpreted as "do not send" instead, leading to missing parameter value errors.

Alternatively, a lot of pre-rolled tools (like Dapper, EF, etc) will take care of this for you.